# joomla index.php file is getting error

Tags: php, joomla

I am not sure whether someone else has this problem before too, but I am really struggling with this error, it says:

```
mark('afterLoad') : null;
// Instantiate the application.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
// Initialise the application.
    $app->initialise();
// Mark afterIntialise in the profiler.
    JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;
// Route the application. $app->route();
// Mark afterRoute in the profiler.
    JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRoute') : null;
// Dispatch the application.
    $app->dispatch();
// Mark afterDispatch in the profiler.
    JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterDispatch') : null;
// Render the application.
    $app->render();
// Mark afterRender in the profiler.
    JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRender') : null;
// Return the response.
    echo $app;
```

I have Joomla 1.7.3 and in localhost in my computer it works everything fine, but when I upload to the server it get that error, how come what is cousing this error can anyone please show me any way how to get rid of it?
does it have to do something with the php version from the server part???

Comment: Check the joomla config file(config.php), check htaccess..what php version you are using?  Check this link for technical requirements --http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html Check the server php version

Comment: I am using PHP version  5.3.8  and the server where i have uploaded joomla it has less version 5.1 something, do you think this might be the error of the php version, and what do you mean in htaccess what should I do here?

Comment: Yes, exactly....This is the minimum minimum version 5.2.4 + for the joomla 1.7 and if you are using under this then definitely you are missing :)

Comment: in conf file i have something like this :

public $offline = '0';
 public $offline_message = 'This site is down for maintenance.<br /> Please check back again soon.';
 public $sitename = 'Festival Holding AB';
 public $editor = 'tinymce';
 public $list_limit = '20';
 public $access = '1';
 public $debug = '0';
 public $debug_lang = '0';
 public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
 public $host = 'localhost';
 public $user = 'festival_festab';

im douting on the localhost line should it be different on the server or it should remain same localhost

Comment: No ... i think your php version is causing the trouble and YES u have to change the config.php when you are going to put it at live server.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, two more question, what we have to put instead of localhost when i locate the config.php file in server, and is it possible to update the php version in server???

Answer (score 3):

Points to remember -

1. Check the joomla config file(config.php).
2. check htaccess
3. php version you are using
4. Check the server php version

   Check this link for technical requirements -- [technical requirements](http://joomla.org/technical-requirements.html)

For changing the config.php file, let me assume you have joomla folder under your htdocs or www(if wamp), i.e-
htdocs->Joomla
and you are accessing it like -- `http://localhost/joomla/`

Now when you upload your joomla folder to live server then in config file Check these settings-

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'username';
public $password = '*****';
```

And few more(smtp likewise)

Comment: U are awesome buddy! thousands of thanks to you.... in live server public $host = 'localhost'; still keeps the same as in local,right???

Comment: Yeah you can keep that as localhost as i just checked my config file on cpanel and found it as same ..just change the dbusername, dbpassford as well :) and thanks hoping for a green tick as an accetpted answer :)

Comment: i wish i could make it more :P

Comment: @lulzim something still left?

Comment: +1 for a good answer swapnesh ;) @lulzim, dont forget the green tick ;)